# PlayFramework ~run strange error

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

Am using Play 2.1.0, Everything was fine all of a sudden I get this strange error (Attached snapshot) this is during when i execute `~run` from play console.

Environment : **Windows 7, IntelliJ12, Mysql, JDK 1.6**

Snapshot :

[image]

Error statement: 'is not a directory so descendants can not be called'

Answer (score 12):

The problem occurs if another process has locked `/logs/application.log`. E.g. if you open the log file in Word and then run play, you will see the error

Comment: lol not really.. I didnt even know that such a kind of file exists ..so there is no way that was opened in Word or anyother process.

Comment: Note that this "other process" could also be a second Play instance. Last time I saw the error was because I accedentially started Play twice in two different consoles.

Answer (score 2):

Quit your console or whatever you are using to start your application.
Delete application.log file. Go to your console screen again. Finally retype run and hit enter.

This file will be regenerated and error will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

It seems another play! app is working in the same port, for windows you can terminate the app and run again.

- open console (windows + r)
- netstat -ano
- find which pid uses '9000' port
- taskkill /PID  /f   (type your PID in )

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is that please delete all java.exe apps from Task Manager. Because one of them has locked "/logs/application.log" file. After that you can delete "/logs/application.log" file and when you run your project it generates automatically again.